# Laravel image in email

Tags: laravel, email

I am trying to attach an image to the email by which can not be show image

This code notification

```
return (new MailMessage)
        ->from(config('mail.username'))
        ->subject('Reset Password')
        ->greeting('<img src="http://test.test/img/header/mail_head_en.jpg">')
        ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
        ->line('Your E-mail address ' . ' : ' . $notifiable->email)
        ->action('Reset Password', route('vendor.password.reset', $this->token . '?email=' . urlencode($notifiable->email)))
        ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
```

but ,not show image to email

[image]

Comment: error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage::image()"

Comment: Try to setup with the email template, you can also try->image('IMAGE_URL')

Comment: Then try to send email with email template

Comment: Ok, i'm try. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your terminal or cmd run this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

now go resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php on line no 4

Change

```
{{ $greeting }}
```

to

```
{!! $greeting !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `greeting` section of your mail view file from  `{{ $greeting }}` to `{!! $greeting !!}`